# mkdocstrings not finding module

Tags: python, mkdocs, mkdocstrings

I've hit a bit of a wall with the mkdocstring plugin as it does not seem to load modules as I would have expected.

My folder structure is as such:

```
docs/
  api.md
src/
  module/
    somemodule.py
```

The api.md file looks like this:

```
# API Documentation

::: module.somemodule.MyClass
handler: python
```

The error I get is this:

```
% mkdocs build                                                                                                                                                                     1 ↵ ✹
INFO     -  Cleaning site directory
INFO     -  Building documentation to directory: /site
ERROR    -  mkdocstrings: No module named 'module'
ERROR    -  Error reading page 'api.md':
ERROR    -  Could not collect 'module.somemodule.MyClass'
```

**What I have found in testing:**

- mkdocs runs correctly, generating the expected documentation when excluding the mkdocstrings plugin.
- mkdocstrings plugin works only if I move mypackage to the repo root

Is there some kind of config setting I need to set with the plugin in the mkdocs.yml to get it to recognize the module in the src folder?  All the example I have come across seem to either be outdated or don't work.

Answer (score 2):

Since your package lives under the src folder, you might need to configure the Python handler of mkdocstrings so that it can find it, see https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#paths and https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#finding-modules.

```
plugins:
- mkdocstrings:
    handlers:
      python:
        paths: [src]  # search packages in the src folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing the optional python dependency fixed it for me -

`pip install 'mkdocstrings[python]'`

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue today, turns out there was an error in the py file. I had a function definition returning multiple things,

```py
# this gave me the error
def foo(x) -> x,y: 
  # some logic
  pass
```

```py
# this fixed the problem for me
from typing import Union
def foo(x) -> Union(x,y): 
  # some logic
  pass
```

Look for any syntax or typing based errors, that should probably fix your problem.

Comment: Remember to run mkdocs with the -v option (verbose) when you have an issue. This will most of the time give you a hint on what's wrong. For future readers, see also how to configure where to find modules: https://mkdocstrings.github.io/python/usage/#paths